# Parseval's theorem - Average Power

Tags: power-spectral-density

I want to calculate averaged power of a time-domain signal by means of its spectrum. I guess Parseval is the right tool.

So I sample a sinus of 100 Hz 10000x within one second.

Unfortunately the sum of the squared samples euqals not the sum of the FFT amplitudes (weighted by the number of FFT bins). Where is the mistake?

```
# Some python code

import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create Time Domain Signal for 1 sec
fs = n = 10000    # Samplingfrequency
ti = numpy.linspace(0,1,num=fs)
sx = 1*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*100*ti)    

# Calculate spectrum via FFT and account for scaling n/2
# taking the real fft (rfft) only the positive frequencies are calculated
fx = numpy.fft.rfft(sx)/(n/2)
no_of_points = fx.shape[0]

# Calculate RMS for time domains signal + spectrum
parseval_sx = numpy.sum(sx**2)
parseval_fx = numpy.sum(numpy.abs(fx)**2)/no_of_points

print parseval_sx, " equals not ", parseval_fx
```

Output:

```
4999.5  equals not  0.000199940012002
```

Comment: I have a python example here https://gist.github.com/endolith/1257010#file-parseval-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things going on. First of all, the real FFT function (`rfft`) returns data in a "[packed](http://www.qft.iqfr.csic.es/docs/intel/mkl/mkl_manual/fft/fft_PackedFormats.htm)" format, which means that you don't get the actual FFT data, but its shortened convenient representation. Use the regunal `fft` instead.

Secondly, I don't know where you got the number by which you scale your results on these two lines:

```
fx = numpy.fft.rfft(sx)/(n/2)
parseval_fx = numpy.sum(numpy.abs(fx)**2)/no_of_points
```

None of those make sense to me. So let's fix that.

In order to take an [orthonormal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370089/confused-as-to-how-to-prove-the-basis-of-dft-is-orthonormal) FFT transform (no scaling of components), we need to scale by the square root of the number of points. So here's what I propose:

```
# Some python code

import numpy
import math

# Create Time Domain Signal for 1 sec
fs = n = 10000    # Samplingfrequency
ti = numpy.linspace(0,1,num=fs)
sx = 1*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*100*ti)    

# Calculate spectrum via FFT and account for scaling 1/sqrt(N)
# taking the real fft (rfft) only the positive frequencies are calculated
fx = numpy.fft.fft(sx)/(math.sqrt(len(sx)))

# Calculate RMS for time domains signal + spectrum
parseval_sx = numpy.sum(sx**2)
parseval_fx = numpy.sum(numpy.abs(fx)**2)

print parseval_sx, " equals ", parseval_fx
```

Comment: Your example works fine.   However: 1. By means of the scaling factor n/2 (n is number of time-domain samples) the absolute of the value of the 100th FFT bin (numpy.abs(fx[100])) is exactly the amplitude of the time-domain sinus. This is now no longer valid. 2. Scaling factor no_of_points is due to Parselval's relation for DFT, see last formular on [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem). Why is it missing in your code but nevertheless well working?

Comment: According to [Numpy rfft Doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html) rfft actually outputs the positive frequencies as complex numbers rather than in a "packed" representation. However, when using numpy.fft.rfft in your example one needs to applay a factor of 2 on parseval_fx in order to obtain the correct value. However, why don't you need to use the right scaling of the FFT amplitudes in order to fulfuill parceval?

Comment: SciPy's `rfft` does the packed representation, while NumPy's `rfft` does the complex representation, which is easier to apply to N-dimensional arrays

Comment: `sum(sx**2)` is the total energy, right?  RMS (∝ average power) would be `sqrt(mean(absolute(sx)**2))`?

Comment: @Frank Applying a value of 2 is not the right solution, since the DC frequency and Nyquist frequency bins are only listed once. You may just be careful and multiply the correct bins by 2 after squaring, but Parseval's theorem is a mathematical statement. And code that would get closest to the statement of the theorem, in my opinion, is the one above.

Comment: @endolith The mean operator will not change the outcome (you're multiplying both sides of the equation by a constant), but [Parseval's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem) does not deal with means. It's simply a statement about orthonormality of the Fourier transform.

Comment: I just mean that OP is asking how to calculate average power from the spectrum, and you're giving total energy instead.

Comment: @endolith Yes, I pretty much missed that part. Thanks.

Comment: @Frank I think endolith's answer is much closer to what you were asking about. Perhaps you should accept that one instead.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to calculate average power (proportional to RMS amplitude) with the `rfft`, but it's more complicated because the DC and Nyquist bins are not doubled in the full fft (and the Nyquist bin doesn't exist if *n* is odd).

NumPy's `rfft` is preferred over SciPy's, because it outputs complex numbers, which are compatible with N-dimensional arrays, rather than SciPy's "packed" format.

```
def rms_rfft(spectrum, n=None):
    """
    Use Parseval's theorem to find the RMS value of an even-length signal
    from its rfft, without wasting time doing an inverse real FFT.

    spectrum is produced as spectrum = numpy.fft.rfft(signal)

    For a signal x with an even number of samples, these should produce the
    same result, to within numerical accuracy:

    rms_flat(x) ~= rms_rfft(rfft(x))

    If len(x) is odd, n must be included, or the result will only be
    approximate, due to the ambiguity of rfft for odd lengths.
    """
    if n is None:
        n = (len(spectrum) - 1) * 2
    sq = real(spectrum * conj(spectrum))
    if n % 2:  # odd
        mean = (sq[0] + 2*sum(sq[1:])           )/n
    else:
        mean = (sq[0] + 2*sum(sq[1:-1]) + sq[-1])/n
    root = sqrt(mean)
    return root/sqrt(n)
```

More details here: https://gist.github.com/endolith/1257010