# Why does fourier transforming an analytic signal gives me negative frequency components?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, python, hilbert-transform

I consider an array:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft
from scipy.signal import hilbert

a=np.random.rand(5)
```

First I manually compute the fourier spectrum of the analytic signal,i.e. by zeroing the negative frequency terms and doubling the positive frequency terms:

```
a_spec_manual = fft(a)
a_spec_manual[1:len(a)//2+1] = 2*a_spec_manual[1:len(a)//2+1]
a_spec_manual[len(a)//2+1:] = 0
```

Then I auto-compute the fourier transform of the analytic signal derived from `a`:

```
a_fft_analytic = fft(hilbert(a))
```

I was expecting `a_fft_analytic` to be equal to `a_spec_manual`. However, it is not the case. `a_fft_analytic` does have negative frequency components and I wonder why?

If indeed the first case is correct, is it possible to obtain the fourier spectrum of the analytic signal from real using single fft operation?

Comment: They _are_ equal. Did you mean to use an even `len(a)`? See `assert np.allclose(a_fft_analytic, a_spec_manual)`

Comment: I am sorry, I got confused with the negligible terms in the negative frequencies of the order of 10-17 for `a_fft_analytic` case. Probably these are rounding errors. However, I am actually trying to compute cross-correlations. I will edit the question and post again. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They [aren't negative](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/72518/50076).

For the odd-length case, your code is already correct: `assert np.allclose(a_spec_manual, a_fft_analytic)`.

For the even-length case, the Nyquist bin should not be doubled (briefly, it is already doubled in some sense, see link).

Following your comment: yes, `1e-16` is "float zero" (and for float32 that's `1e-7`). FFT takes no shortcuts (always does compute), so even "perfect" examples won't have exact zeros.